# Facebook oauth retrieve user work?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I asked for a 'work' permission and got this response.work array of all current and previous occupations. How do I get only a current occupation, would this work:

response.work[0].position.name ??

Comment: have you tried it? what did you get?

Comment: yea.. response.work.position.name also works, as it grabs the most recent position... How do I close my own ticket? :)

Comment: How about posting the solution and accept your answer a couple of days later? :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

response.work[0].position.name  worked.